# How to restrict Primefaces inputMask to numbers only?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, input-mask

I want to restrict `p:inputMask` to numbers **only**, and I tried the proposed solutions from:

- [How to restrict an input to numbers only with PrimeFaces inputMask element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848346/how-to-restrict-an-input-to-numbers-only-with-primefaces-inputmask-element)

But none of them worked. I tried these two ways:

```
<p:inputMask id="userNo"  maxlength="2" mask="9?9999" />
```

and

```
<p:inputMask id="userNo"  maxlength="2" >
    <pe:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9_]/i"/>
</p:inputMask>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that approach is right but I noticed that you don't put `value` attribute on `inputMask`. 
Do you try to put it on?

> *Edit:
>   These solutions works:*

**inputMaskTest.xhtml:**

```
<h3>Input Mask:</h3>
<h:form id="form">
    <p:outputLabel value="Input Mask only number " for="userNo1" />
    <p:inputMask id="userNo1"  maxlength="2" mask="9?9999" value="#{inputMaskView.number}"/>

    <p:outputLabel value="Input Mask only Number Primeface Ext " for="userNo2" />
    <p:inputMask id="userNo2" maxlength="2" value="#{inputMaskView.number}">
        <pe:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9_]/i" />
    </p:inputMask>
</h:form>
```

**InputMaskView.java:**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "inputMaskView")
@ViewScoped 
public class InputMaskView {
  private String number;

  public String getNumber() {
    return number;
  }
  public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
  }
}
```

- see also: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37665

Comment: If you took a closer look, it's the same approach in both ways.

Comment: Yes, I also mean both. Only difference is value attribute. Did you try to put it on InputMask?

Comment: I've just tried and post my solution and it works (accepts only numbers). I've posted it on my answer. Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Whole number only, no decimal, no negative, no thousand separator.

It has several applications, for example code reception.

It is like:

```
<p:inputNumber minValue="1" decimalPlaces="0" thousandSeparator="" value="#{myclass.myVariable}"/>
```